# Deserialize JSON from Google Cloud pub/sub and preserve UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, json, utf-8, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Note - I'm posting this as a 'Q & A' as I haven't found an existing question on SO that matches the specific scenario of ***deserializing JSON from a Google Cloud pub/sub stream and preserving the UTF-8 character set***. I have a solution for this and I want to post an answer to make it available to the community (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):

> If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you
>   would like to document that knowledge in public so that others
>   (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and
>   answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

---

I'm receiving JSON from a Google Cloud pub/sub URL, and I know that it's using UTF-8 encoding. I can see this by examining the response I get when I make a request directly to the pub/sub URL using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

I can deserialize the JSON like this (using the [Google Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson)):

```
        URL myUrl= new URL("myUrl");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

        MyResponseObject myResponseObject;

        try {           
            myResponseObject = new Gson()
                    .fromJson(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())), MyResponseObject.class);
        }
```

When I inspect `myResponseObject` in Eclipse, some of the characters in the JSON that are outside of the ASCII character set aren't correctly displayed.

Then, after I add the resulting dataset into BigQuery, I see characters like this in the BigQuery data, in place of certain characters that don't belong to the ASCII set.

��

The '�' is an indicator that means that the encoding hasn't been correctly handled and that some text encoding has been lost. How do I preserve the encoding?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to set the encoding for the input stream from the Google Cloud pub/sub. I can do that for a Google Cloud pub/sub stream like this:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import com.google.api.client.util.Charsets;

    URL myUrl= new URL("myUrl");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

    MyResponseObject myResponseObject;

    Charset cs = Charsets.UTF_8;

    try {           
        myResponseObject = new Gson()
                .fromJson(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), cs)), MyResponseObject.class);
    }
```